# Control order of Tab10 colors in colormap

Tags: matplotlib, colormap

I would like to get a colormap with the first two colors of the Tab10 palette (blue and orange). But

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.get_cmap('tab10', 2)
```

gives me the first and the last color of the palette

[cmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2dEa.png)

Is there an easy way to control the order of the colors? My intention is to have a color scheme identical to the matplotlib default for categorical values.

Comment: `cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(plt.cm.tab10.colors[:2])`